# PySerial: Data corrupted when reading from serial port

Tags: python, arduino, msp430

Trying to read the data from serial port using pySerial module, I am unable to reconstruct the data that I send from a microcontroller (MSP430).

Microcontroller is programmed as below:

```
Serial.print(0x20); //32 in decimal
delay(200);
Serial.print(0x20); //32 in decimal
delay(200);
Serial.print(0x00); //0 in decimal
delay(500);
Serial.print(0x15); //21 in decimal
delay(500);
```

Above code is executed in infinite loop.

In Python code, I am just reading 120 bytes using the following code and inspecting the serial port variable.

```
import serial 
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 115200, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,) 
cycles_needed = 120
chars=[]
s=ser.read(cycles_needed)
for i in range(len(s)):
    print s[i]
```

The output of the above code is

```
3
2
3
2
0
2
1
3
2
3
2
0
2
1
```

Can someone please explain me why the data is split into nibbles while ideally, it had to read the data serially byte-by-byte.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino [documentation of `Serial.print()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) says:

> Prints data to the serial port as human-readable ASCII text.

So the value 32 ends up as two characters, `3` and `2`.

To write binary data, use `write()` instead.